¿Cómo ajustar el tamaño de las letras en CSS para que se alineen correctamente en un juego tipo Wordle?
Estoy desarrollando un juego tipo Wordle y estoy teniendo problemas con la alineación de las letras. Aquí está mi HTML y CSS.


.letter {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  min-width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<div class='row'>
  <span class='letter'>N</span>
  <span class='letter'>G</span>
  <span class='letter'>E</span>
  <span class='letter'>L</span>
</div>

<div class='row'>
  <span class='letter'>A</span>
  <span class='letter'>P</span>
  <span class='letter'>P</span>
  <span class='letter'>L</span>
  <span class='letter'>E</span>
</div>



El problema es que las letras no se alinean correctamente en todas las filas y dispositivos. ¿Cómo puedo ajustar el tamaño de las letras y su alineación para que se vean uniformes y bien alineadas?

¿A que te refieres que no están alineadas? yo las veo alineadas :S

Actualmente tienes así la alineación:

Si lo que buscas es tenerlo en una sola fila tal que:

Puedes intentar de esta manera:


.letter {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  min-width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-row{
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
<div class="main-row">
  <div class='row'>
    <span class='letter'>N</span>
    <span class='letter'>G</span>
    <span class='letter'>E</span>
    <span class='letter'>L</span>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <span class='letter'>A</span>
    <span class='letter'>P</span>
    <span class='letter'>P</span>
    <span class='letter'>L</span>
    <span class='letter'>E</span>
  </div>
</div>



Donde te alinea por así decirlo todo el texto dentro de los rows en una sola fila.
Se añadió una nueva clase .main-rows para alinear dichas rows.
